# Duplicate values in filter by in Dynamics 365 View

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have issues with filter by in dynamics 365 view. When we select Filter By to filter column which is a lookup column has multiple duplicate values in suggestions which is auto populated.

Can I make it in a way it only shows values which are present in view

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have a lot of records with the same name?